# Olympic sports with mixed team?

Tags: trivia, olympics, gender

What are, if they exist, Olympic sports (both winter and summers Games) where there are team composed by men and women?

Comment: Are you considering Paralympics also?

Comment: [Mixed doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_at_the_Summer_Olympics#Events) in tennis.

Comment: There is no mixed-sex shooting at the Summer Olympics although there is a proposal for 3 mixed pair events for Tokyo.

Comment: The question was about existing sport, anyway it is better to add references/links

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia [Category:Mixed sports at the Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mixed_sports_at_the_Olympics) contains:

- Mixed doubles badminton at the Summer Olympics‎
- Equestrian at the Summer Olympics‎
- Ice dancing at the Winter Olympics
- Pair skating at the Winter Olympics‎
- Mixed-sex shooting at the Summer Olympics‎
- Mixed doubles tennis at the Summer Olympics‎

---

A further event, [Mixed Doubles Curling](http://www.worldcurling.org/mixed-doubles-curling-confirmed-for-pyeongchang-2018) is planned for the Winter Olympics 2018 in PyeongChang

---

Wikipedia article [Women at the Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_at_the_Olympics) mentions that:

> While team mixed gendered sports are not competed at the Olympics, some mixed gendered events are included. They include equestrian sports, shooting and sailing where men and women compete against each other. In shooting and sailing, women were originally only allowed to competed in mixed gendered events. Single gender events for these sports were not added until a later date.

Answer (score 2):

The events of the Equestrian sports in the summer Olympics are always with [mixed teams](http://www.olympic.org/photos/equestrian-great-britain-celebrate-winning-their-silver-medal-in-eventing).

In the Show Jumping, Dressage and Eventing disciplines men and women compete on equal terms.  This is both in the individual and team events.

The sport of Equestrianism has always been mixed, not just in the Olympic games.